# Get stuck while order upload using CSV file via magento advance data profile

Tags: magento

Here is my Action XML  but its give me an error . Can anyone please suggest me how can i solve this.

```
    <action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="save">
   <var name="type">file</var>
   <var name="path">var/import</var>
   <var name="filename"><![CDATA[orders.csv]]></var>
   <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="unparse">
<var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">false</var>
    <var name="number_of_records">100</var>
    <var name="adapter">sales/convert_orderr</var>
    <var name="method">unparse</var>
</action>

<action type="sales/convert_order" method="save">
   <var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
</action>
```

Thanks much.

Update : The error is :  Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Order::addException(Array ( [0] => Unable to run action method: save [1] => FATAL ) )

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks much for quick reply .The error i got : Fatal error: Call to a member function setDataflowProfile() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\ruland\app\code\core\Mage\Dataflow\Model\Profile.php on line 204 .

Comment: I did some edit on my code but still i am getting error messages.

Comment: Its seem to me ,we have to write custom adapter class for uploading order CSV file! Any idea guys ?

Comment: @noich , please review this.